# Stable and free CAD for OS X 10.11, El Capitan?

Tags: macos

Are there any stable and free CAD programs for OS X 10.11, El Capitan?

I just need to review one CAD file. I find many CAD programs for OS X 10.10, Yosemite, but not for El Capitan.

Comment: What file format does the application need to open? AutoCAD DWG and DXF?

Comment: What makes you think that CAD applications for 10.10 will not work in 10.11?

Answer (score 2):

If you only need to review a file, try using a free demonstration of:

- [AutoCAD](http://www.autodesk.com/products/autocad/overview)
- [MacDraft](http://www.microspot.com/)
- [Vectorworks](http://www.vectorworks.net/architect/)
- [SketchUp](http://www.sketchup.com)

For more CAD applications on the Mac, see [Pure Mac's CAD section](http://www.pure-mac.com/cad.html) and [AppleCAD's extensive list](http://www.applecad.com/cad-software-list/). Most will work with OS X 10.11.